# How to regenerate a package.json and package-lock.json file for a node js project?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Is there a way to regenerate a `package.json` file from the source code, I have cloned a work repo but the other developer had `.gitignore` file as this:

.gitignore

```
node_modules/
.env
package-lock.json
package.json
*.json
```

Hence I have the source code but I can not run it until I have all the dependencies. How could I achieve this?
I tried

```
npm init -y
npm i
```

But it did not install the dependencies

Comment: Ask the other dev to push the pacakge.json file to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

I think the shortest way to solve this is to go through the code and find the required packages, then install them via NPM i.